# Show that $(B)_{kl}=\sum _{i,j}(U)_{ik}(A)_{ij}(U)_{jl}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $U$ be a orthongal $n$ by $n$ matrix. And let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix that is not diagonal. Define $B = U^TAU.$ Show that 
$$(B)_{kl}=\sum _{i,j}(U)_{ik}(A)_{ij}(U)_{jl}.$$

I'm not totally sure which assumptions I need for this theorem, because this is part of a proof in the book. And I don't understand how this part is decuced.

Of course I know how regular matrix multiplication:

[image]

But multiplying 3 matrices, I get 2 sums, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
B_{k,l} &= \sum \limits _{i=1} ^n (U^t)_{k,i}(AU)_{i,l}\\
        &= \sum\limits _{i=1} ^n (U)_{i,k}(AU)_{i,l}\\
        &= \sum\limits _{i=1} ^n (U)_{i,k}\sum\limits _{j=1} ^n (A)_{i,j}(U)_{j,l}\\
        &= \sum\limits _{i=1} ^n \sum\limits _{j=1} ^n (U)_{i,k}(A)_{i,j}(U)_{j,l}
\end{align}